# RuntimeError: invalid argument 1:cannot perform reduction function max on tensor with no elements because the operation does not have an identity

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, bert-language-model

I am using a Pre-trained BERT model (FlauBERT) to produce features to give as input to multiple classifiers. In the example, they just show how to proceed for one signle sentence but I get a whole file (dataframe ) of approximately 40 000 sentences. So giving it all the model consume a lot of memory and I was looking for a way to pass small batch of sentences to the model so as to not created a killing of the  system or "out of memory" error. I come up with a solution which is supposed to pass 2000 lines at at the time tp be process and then finally , I concatenate all the batch in one single numpy array. But for some reasons I get the following error :

```
layer : <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
layer : <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
layer : <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
layer : <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
layer : <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
layer : <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
layer : <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
layer : <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
layer : <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "knn_case_1.py", line 83, in <module>
    train_data_x_emb, mdl = get_flaubert_layer(train_data_x)
  File "knn_case_1.py", line 45, in get_flaubert_layer
    layer = flaubert(token_ids)
  File "/ho/geta/kelod/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 532, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/ho/geta/kelod/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_flaubert.py", line 176, in forward
    assert lengths.max().item() <= slen
RuntimeError: invalid argument 1:cannot perform reduction function max on tensor with no elements because the operation does not have an identity
```

Here is the script : for reproductible environment : import transfromers ans scikit learn library

```
train_data = pd.read_csv('./corpus_train/corpus_ix_aug_FMC.csv', sep='\t')
# read the train and test dataset
#train_data = pd.read_csv('./corpus_train/corpus_or_et_aug_avec_all_FM')
train_data_x = train_data.verbatim
train_data_y = train_data.etiquette

def spliterate(buf, chunk):
    for start in range(0, buf.size, chunk):
        yield buf[start:start + chunk]

def get_flaubert_layer(texte):
    
    modelname = "flaubert-base-cased"
    
    flaubert, log = FlaubertModel.from_pretrained(modelname, output_loading_info=True)
    flaubert_tokenizer = FlaubertTokenizer.from_pretrained(modelname, do_lowercase=False)
    tokenized = texte.apply((lambda x: flaubert_tokenizer.encode(x, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=512)))
    #tokenized = flaubert_tokenizer.encode(elt, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=512)
    max_len = 0
    for i in tokenized.values:
        if len(i) > max_len:
            max_len = len(i)
    padded = np.array([i + [0] * (max_len - len(i)) for i in tokenized.values])
    print(np.array(padded).shape)
    print(padded)
    attention_mask = np.where(padded != 0, 1, 0)
    print(attention_mask)
    print(attention_mask.shape)
    last_layer_ = []
    for tmp in spliterate(padded, 2000):
        if len(tmp) != 0:
            token_ids = torch.tensor(tmp)
            with torch.no_grad():
                layer = flaubert(token_ids)
                layer = layer [0][:,0,:].numpy()
                print("layer :", type(layer))
                last_layer_.append(layer)
            
            
                #last_layer += layer
        else:
            None 
    print("last layer_ :", type(last_layer_))
    print(len(last_layer_))     
    last_layer_np = numpy.stack(last_layer_, axis=0)
    print(len(last_layer_np))
    
    return last_layer_np, modelname 

train_data_x_emb, mdl = get_flaubert_layer(train_data_x)
```

padded variable look like this :

```
[[    1  1041 21565 ...     0     0     0]
 [    1   391   177 ...     0     0     0]
 [    1   150 14206 ...     0     0     0]
 ...
 [    1   150  5799 ...     0     0     0]
 [    1    59    48 ...     0     0     0]
 [    1   175    65 ...     0     0     0]]
```

Comment: my guess is the last chunk is empty because you've sliced beyond the end

Comment: Ah ok! Do you know perhaps how to deal with it?

Comment: You wrote the chunking code, didn't you?  Can't you test it and make sure it provides the correct size chunks all the time?  Remember, Python (and numpy) allows you to slice "off the end", possibly returning a empty list or array.

Comment: @hpaulj the last chunk is not the same as the others, whatI did it is to ignore it. I said that if a chunk is == 0 , then None and the script could work and produce all the chunk , the real problem is to concatenate all, so that it is similar to the dataset because I then send to a classifier for traning. See below script